# Detect IndexPath of UIButton in TableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have added a `UIButton` to a prototype cell that is connected to the following method. There are several prototype cells that get populated on the `UITableViewController`. However, whenever I run it the `path.row` is always returning `0` for every table cell.

```
- (IBAction)deleteButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[button superview];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"You deleted %ld",(long)path.row);

}
```

Comment: the `superview` of your `button` is not a `UITableViewCell`, it is a `contentView` of an `UITableViewCell` only.

Comment: Is the `superview` of the `contentView` a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: it is more likely. :)

Comment: Do not assume any specific sequence of calls to `superview` is going to give you the cell. This seems to change with each version of iOS.